# C# LINQ divide by zero error when using multiple integers to make a capture rate

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

Do you have any idea how I can fix this LINQ issue with a divide by zero.

I have a list of objects that gives the various reasons why a quote did not complete and tries to sort by the capture rate.

```
int NoOfQuotes //this is the number of quotes
int NoOfQuotesBooked //these quotes completed
int DuplicateQuotes //these are duplicate quotes that we don't want to count.
```

The capture rate is `NoOfQuotesBooked / (NoOfQuotes  - DuplicateQuotes).`

If `NoOfQuotes - DuplicateQuotes == 0`, it should return back `0.0` for the sort.

```
_customerSummaryItems = _customerSummaryItems.OrderByDescending(x => (x.NoOfQuotesBooked / (x.NoOfQuotes - x.DuplicateQuotes)))
           .ThenBy(x => x.CompanyName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
           .ThenBy(x => x.LastName)
           .ToList();
```

No matter how I try and sort this, I can’t get the Linq to compile properly and so I must be screwing something up. How would I add a divide by zero check in this sort?

Comment: is this EF or some other Linq provider (other than Linq to Objects)?

Comment: What compiler error are you getting?

Comment: this is basics in regards to why you are getting a Divide By Zero Error makes me wonder if you even debugged it or just did the good old `Code and Run` Scenario [C# Basics Divid By Zero](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dividebyzeroexception)

Answer (score 3):

So just check for the result and do the calculation:

```
_customerSummaryItems = _customerSummaryItems
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.NoOfQuotes - x.DuplicateQuotes != 0  
                           ? (x.NoOfQuotesBooked / (x.NoOfQuotes - x.DuplicateQuotes)))
                           : 0.0)
    .ThenBy(x => x.CompanyName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.LastName)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want:

```
_customerSummaryItems = _customerSummaryItems
    .OrderByDescending(x => 
        x.NoOfQuotes == x.DuplicateQuotes 
        ? 0.0 
        : (x.NoOfQuotesBooked / (x.NoOfQuotes - x.DuplicateQuotes)))
    .ThenBy(x => x.CompanyName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.LastName)
    .ToList();
```